# Google maps getting current location

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Whenever i try to get the lattitude, the map crashes, there is nothing in the logcat.

Sorry for asking the basic, but i am new to Android.

Thanks in advance!

**My code:**

```
 private void setupMap() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            //get the loacation manger object form system service
            LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //get the criteria object for provider
            Criteria criteria= new Criteria();

            //get the name of best provider
            String provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);

            //get current Location
            Location currentLocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            //set maptype
            googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

             //Get lattitude and longitude
            //double latitude=currentLocation.getLatitude();
            //double longitude=currentLocation.getLongitude();

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf( latitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    //enable my location layer of google map

   }
```

**The log cat:**

```
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): Process: com.example.test, PID: 8811
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.example.test.map.setupMap(map.java:63)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.example.test.map.onCreate(map.java:36)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
12-04 12:16:11.652: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` has the possibility of returning `null` which may cause your app to crash with a `NullPointerException`.

Alternatively, you can go over the [`Location Strategies`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) docs provided by Android and use the method provided there:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager 
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define a listener that responds to location updates 
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() { 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        // Display a marker on the GoogleMap
    } 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {} 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {} 
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {} 
  }; 
// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
// NOTE : PLEASE ADJUST THE FREQUENCY OF UPDATES PROPERLY
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You can also use `requestSingleUpdate()` if you just want a single update to the user's position.

Comment: I have One more query though...  Whenever i try to Toast in the onLocationChanged method... it is carried on even if the app is closed...!!!

Comment: You are asking for update`s`. Like the docs say, you need to stop the updates after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```
Location currentLocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

is not null?

you should implement a locationChangeListener and use that Location

```
googlemap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
//Get lattitude and longitude
double latitude=location.getLatitude();
double longitude=location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... ITs apparently returning null...  I used the code snippet of yours but apparantly ForceClosing the app..

Answer (score 0):

Have you have **turned on locations or gps**  in your mobile ?  Also **getLastKnownLocation()** have high possibility of returning null value. It would be better if you fix your log and post it too.